# Is it possible to access Slim symbols from code with FitSharp?

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, fitsharp

According to [FitSharp issue 123](https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/issues/123) it wasn't possible to in July 2014.  I was wondering if this has changed in the years since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way defined in the Slim protocol to do this.  We'd have to inspect the parameter types to see if a method wants the Slim symbols passed to it, e.g.

```
using fitSharp.Machine.Engine;
...
public void GetTheSymbols(Symbols symbols) { ...}
```